# Looking for a tool to manage all maintenance work on my PC

Tags: windows, maintenance

I'm looking for a tool to manage the maintenance tasks on a Windows PC. Things like disk defrag, antivirus, update software and any other maintenance.
This should **not** be an all-in-one solutions, with these features built in. Rather, it should be a framework to automate other tools (like CCleaner, Defragler etc.).
Many tasks should be run periodically (with different frequencies). I'm looking for one tool to manage all these tasks.

Answer (score 1):

[**AutoIt**](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) is a good tool to automate a lot of GUI based Windows applications.

> AutoIt v3 is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for automating the Windows GUI and general scripting. It uses a combination of simulated keystrokes, mouse movement and window/control manipulation in order to automate tasks in a way not possible or reliable with other languages (e.g. VBScript and SendKeys). AutoIt is also very small, self-contained and will run on all versions of Windows out-of-the-box with no annoying "runtimes" required!
>
> AutoIt was initially designed for PC "roll out" situations to reliably automate and configure thousands of PCs. Over time it has become a powerful language that supports complex expressions, user functions, loops and everything else that veteran scripters would expect.

Is this the kind of stuff you are looking for?

Comment: Not exactly. I know I can automate and schedule most of this stuff. I was looking for something that saves most of the work of automation. Some tool that has prior knowledge of these maintenance application (with the ability to add more ass needed), and can just "plug them in" as needed. Maybe this is something missing in the market :)